# How do I setup hello.js to access Twitter?

Tags: twitter, hello.js

I'm trying to write a simple Javascript page for sending a tweet with a picture using Hello.js. I've used [this demo](http://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/twitter.html#hello-twitter-) as a starting point but a lot isn't really explained. My init looks like this:

```
hello.init({
    'twitter' : '****'
});
```

It says [here](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy) that I need to "Register your client_id + client_secret at the OAuth Proxy service". But how do I do this? The Twitter page for my app shows:

1. Consumer Key.
2. Consumer Secret.
3. Access Token.
4. Access Token Secret.

The registration at https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/ asks for:

1. reference.
2. domain.
3. client_id.
4. client_secret.

What do I set these to? Do the reference and domain have to match something in my code? Are the client_id and client_secret the Consumer or Access Token parameters?

Answer (score 3):

The reference is the network name, like "twitter", "dropbox", etc.

The domain is the domain your calling from. It can work with something like "http://localhost:8080".

For Twitter, the client_id is the Consumer Key (API Key) and the client_secret is the Consumer Secret (API Secret).

Once this is done, in your JS code you just have to add something like this:

```
  hello.init({
    twitter: '<your Consumer Key>'
  }, {});
```

And then a button with the following code should work:

```
<button onclick="hello( 'twitter' ).login()">Login with Twitter</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of problems with hello.js and Twitter, until I finally found out:

- If you don't have a working domain yet (you are developing), you ought to write 127.0.0.1 in the callback URL within the settings of your [twitter app](http://dev.twitter.com).

-Within the same settings, make sure you select "Allow the app to sign up with twitter".

-Your init function should look like this:

```
hello.init({
    twitter : 'xxxxxx'
 },{redirect_uri : 'localhost',
     oauth_proxy : 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com',
      oauth_version: 'xx' // probably 1.0a with hello.js
});
```

Comment: It is the server that is going to authenticate your (in this case) Twitter API key.

Comment: @NatiKrisi http://auth-server.herokuapp.com is the OAuth proxy server run by the developer of hello.js